# How to allow other apps to add choices to a model's fields

Tags: django, django-models, choicefield

I have a `NotificationEvent` model which allows for generating Notification data so that I can then send messages to my users regarding what is going on in the site.

The `NotificationEvent`model contains a `category` field. Several types of notifications can be generated by users.

By default, only two categories are available ('New post' and 'New comment').

I would like for my other apps to be able to add new categories inside their own folders, either in something like a `notifications.py` file, or by adding some code to their models.

I don't know how to generate the choices based on the contents of other apps.

Here is my code so far :

#### In notifications.models :

```
NOTIFICATION_CATEGORIES = (('NEW_POST', 'New post'), ('NEW_COMMENT', 'New comment'))
# More choices can be added by doing (?)

class NotificationEvent(models.Model):

    ''' Notification events are usually triggered by user actions and kept as a log of what has happened '''

    category = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=NOTIFICATION_CATEGORIES)

    sender = models.ForeignKey(User)
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def AddNotificationCategory(DB_VALUE, humean_readable_value):
    NOTIFICATION_CATEGORIES += ('DB_VALUE', 'humean_readable_value'),
```

#### In each app where I want to generate new notification categories :

```
from notifications.models import AddNotificationCategory

AddNotificationCategory('NEW_LIKE', 'New like')
```

What is the best way to deal with this situation ?

Comment: Why don't you create a `Category` model and let each model that has `category` field point to that model? In this case, if you want more choices, just add more data to `Category`.

Comment: Thanks @ShangWang. Is there no way to do this without the database ? I was considering setting a "NOTIFICATION_EVENT_CATEGORIES" object in settings.py and just adding to it.

Comment: Then don't do it in the settings.py, settings.py is for django general settings. You could use a function to return choices instead.